# Switch/Comparison Statement Issue

Tags: javascript

For some reason I can't get my switch statement, I'm new to Javascript and I've got the feeling my issue is more to do with the 'cat==="string"' part rather than the switch.

For the sake of this Example assume the value of 'data.cat' is Starters.

```
function (data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
         if (!data.success) {
            // An error was thrown in the controller
            alert(data.message);
         } else {
             switch (cat = data.cat) { //data.cat is Starters
                 case 0:
                    cat === "Starters";
                    console.log("Test a= " + cat);
                    break;
                 case 1:
                    cat === "Mains";
                    console.log("Test b= " + cat);
                    break;
                 case 2:
                    cat === "Deserts";
                    console.log("Test c= " + cat);
                    break;
                 default:
                    console.log("Shit.." + data.cat);
                    break;
             }
         }
     });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/76fe9kk7/3/

As you can see from the fiddle, the log reports the Default. Why is this?

Comment: Learn [the way `switch` is supposed to be used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) before asking. *Even though the first case (0) should equal true* doesn't make sense at all. Are you saying that `0` is equal to `"Starters"`?

Comment: As I stated in a comment to Plalx it was a stupid miss-understanding on my behalf. After reading this http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp example I was under the impression you numbered switches, just because. As I now know, I was wrong. For the record however I did spend a good deal of time trying to fix it myself. I just completely overlooked the whole "case "value"" thing. My Bad..

Comment: By the way, W3Schools is not a place to learn JavaScript with high quality. Take a look at [the guide on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide), it provides tutorials with much greater depth (and correct information). Clearer explanation is also a win. Btw, that link is not a duplicate of your question. (Did I just use "by the way" twice in a single comment?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var cat = "Starters";
switch (cat) {
    case "Starters":
        console.log("Test a= " + cat);
        break;
    case "Mains":
        console.log("Test b= " + cat);
        break;
    case "Deserts":
        console.log("Test c= " + cat);
        break;
    default:
        console.log("Shit.." + cat);
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why would it every enter anything other than default if the switch is made on a string value and every cases expect a numeric value?

"For the sake of this Example assume the value of 'data.cat' is Starters."

In this case it  means that `switch (cat = data.cat)` is basically saying `switch ('Starters')`. Obviously that will always go in the default case.

Comment: Gah, I see where I've got it wrong now. I thought case 0, case 1, etc was a way of ordering the switch statements. I suppose that's what happens when you rely on W3S examples without full understanding. Thank-you so much.